# Cada que utilizar a super

Tags: android

Tengo una duda, como funciona

```
FullImageActivity.super.onBackPressed();
```

Lo tengo dentro de un onClickListener

Comment: como funciona el codigo que tengo en el onClickLIstener

Comment: pudieras ser más específico.

Comment: se que el onBackPressed regresa a la actividad que tenia anterior pero no se porque utiliza a super

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se utiliza la palabra clave `super` se está llamando a la implementación más próxima que se hereda del método llamado, en tu caso el método `onBackPressed`. Puedes aprender más en la [documentación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) sobre el tema.